# How to use the built-in generic delegate `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` provided by the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#

1. Generally, how shall I use the built-in generic delegate
   `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` provided by the .NET Framework?
2. Specifically, I saw an example

   ```
   Class MyEvent{
       ...
       public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomeEvent; 
       ...
   }

   Class EventDemo{

       ...

       void MyEventHandler(Object sender, MyEventArgs e){
           ...
       }

       ...

       myEvent = new MyEvent();

       myEvent.SomeEvent += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(MyEventHandler);

   }
   ```

   Can

   ```
   myEvent.SomeEvent += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(MyEventHandler);
   ```

   be replaced by

   ```
   myEvent.SomeEvent += MyEventHandler;
   ```

   In particular, does `new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>()` try to convert
   the function `MyEventHandler` from one type to another type?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the specific delegate type, nor the generic nature of a delegate type. The difference in the syntax is simply that the compiler knows how to infer the instantiation of a delegate instance from a method group name directly. You can omit the new operator and constructor call in _any_ context where a new delegate instance is desired. See marked duplicate for details.